# Is it possible to replace Css File by end user?

Tags: css, html, mobile

There is a website with a form which I need to fill almost every week, the problem is that this website is not mobile friendly and it makes it difficult to fill via mobile.

Is it possible to program an app that recognizes the site's url and replaces its Css file with a mobile friendly one that I will write and reload the site?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Firefox mobile, you could install Stylish (https://userstyles.org/) and write your own set of CSS that overrides the site's.

I have done things like that both with greasemonkey and Stylish and if you can write CSS, it can improve the site.

There is no general out-of-the-box solution for making sites mobile-friendly, though.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! thx alot.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible, everytime the styling of anything changes you need to re-load the page, and when you do the website reloads the css from the server, so your app will need to load the CSS again & you'll have to reload the page again which reloads the css from the server, etc.

You can change the CSS styling through 'Inspect Element' (press F12 in most browsers) and the changes take effect emmediatly, but this isn't the case when changing CSS files.

Comment: *You can change the CSS styling through 'Inspect Element' (press F12 in most browsers)* Is that possible in mobile browsers though? OP's looking to change the CSS while on a mobile device.

Comment: Pretty sure that there's an inspect element yes.